# Cross Correlation with Discrete signals

Tags: matlab

How to perform cross correlation when one discrete signal has negative samples?
For example we have :

y=[1 2 3 4 5]
h0=[7 8 9]

but the ho starts from -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the regular cross correlation.
Afterwards set the lags vector accordingly.